Why doesn’t Lenovo Thinkpad Dock Gen 2 40AS work with a Huawei Matebook D14 2020 laptop?
I have an Huawei Matebook D14 2020 (Intel Core i5). In my company office, I can use with the USB-C port the docking station Dell D6000 with mouse, keyboard and external monitors.
I bought a docking station for a Lenovo Thinkpad 40AS. However, this one in not working with my computer.
I tried to install all the drivers, update them etc… but nothing seems to work.
My guess is that Dell D6000 uses DisplayLink technology whereas Lenovo Thinkpad Dock Gen 2 40AS doesn't.
Is there a way to make the Lenovo Thinkpad Dock Gen 2 40AS docking station use this technology?

There likely isn't any way to fix it. Most of these docks are made proprietary specifically to prevent this, other times functionality is the cause (can't use a thunderbolt dock on a PC without thunderbolt, as an example).
In your case, it's a proprietary dock mostly made for Thinkpads, but can apparently be used on certain Dells and HPs, but NOT Huawei. Next time, you'll need to check the compatibility list for the dock/laptop you want or already own.
